# Spring Boot security is redirecting user to home page after successful login instead of the page prior to login page request

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

This is my security config in spring boot application:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/secured/**").hasAuthority("USER").antMatchers("/", "/**").permitAll();
http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login-error").and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/");
http.httpBasic();
```

No matter from where I login, user is being directed to homepage "/" again instead of the page requested prior to login.

For example, `http://localhost:8080/products?type-name=...` is not secured and anyone can view it. However, if user tries to login from this page, they are getting redirected to homepage instead of staying on `http://localhost:8080/products?type-name=...` after logging in. How can I configure the security to prevent this?

Even when logging in from `/secured/..` urls, user is getting redirect to homepage.

I noticed that when my custom login page is returned through get method:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginGetHandler(HttpServletRequest req) {
        System.out.println("Referer: " + req.getHeader("referer")); 
        return "login";
    }
```

referer is the expected url to which the user needs to be redirected.

But after submitting the login form, the referer is changed from the expected url to `"http://localhost:8080/login"`. So, when I implement a successhandler to redirect to referer url, user is being redirected to login page again despite successful login.

Also, when I use the default spring boot + security configuration, the application is able to correctly redirect the user to previous url before login. Is there anyway to preserve that in custom config?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SavedRequest from Spring

The original request is represented by the DefaultSavedRequest object, which can be accessed as a session attribute named SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/savedrequest/SavedRequest.html

Comment: When I tried to get saved request, it is coming as null. I noticed that when my login page is returned through get method: 

@RequestMapping(path = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginGetHandler(HttpServletRequest req) {
        System.out.println("Referer: " + req.getHeader("referer")); 
        return "login";
    }

referer is the expected url to which the user needs to be redirected. 

But after submitting the login form, the referer is changed from the expected url to "http://localhost:8080/login".

Answer (score 0):

I've bypassed this problem by getting referer url in my login page method, adding it to the model attribute and sending the url as a hidden form field to login url from where I could get the url back as request param in successhandler bean like this:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginGetHandler(HttpServletRequest req,Model model) {
    System.out.println("Referer: " + req.getHeader("referer"));
    model.addAttribute("referer",req.getHeader("referer")); 
    return "login";
}
```

Passing the referer as hidden form field to login url, I'm able to retrieve that url back in the AuthenticationSuccessHandler bean and redirect the response.

```
@Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        return (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) -> {
            String parameter = request.getParameter("referer");
            System.out.println("redirect url: " + parameter);
            response.sendRedirect(parameter);
        };
    }
```

Is this a viable option or are there any risks in this approach?